# What is a simple process for obtaining an OAuth Bearer Token for an Azure AD authenticated Web Application?

Tags: vb.net, rest, azure

I've been searching for the past few days and I just keep hitting a wall on this. I've tried several different examples and solutions and nothing seems to work. So here's my situation:

I have an Azure deployed web application.

I want to call an API in API Management (get) to retrieve some data for the app. I can get it working perfectly from my dev environment on my local machine using ntlmauthentication. Once deployed to the Dev site in Azure that no longer works because you can't use NTLM. I can use basic or, as was explained to me, assemble an authorization header using Bearer .

I'd like to take the bearer approach, as the user is already authenticated in the web app at this point when they access it (prompted with Microsoft login).

The app is developed in VB.NET (granted I can always convert C# examples), but I am missing something fundamental here. My examples are a mess at this point from trying several approaches :) .

If I can get some guidance or an example here I'd be really appreciative. NOTE: A lot of examples I saw used a method in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory no longer exists: Context.AqcuireToken. Unless I'm using the wrong library, the only offer is AqcuiretokenAsync and that is proving to be a pain for me to debug (I'll admit I'm not the most experienced coder).

Anyway, any help would be sincerely appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide more info. I'm looking for an easy path forward here, if it exists.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to configure things on Azure too https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2/

Comment: The Azure Config portion is all done. That's the page I most recently used as an example. I have my client id, tenant id, etc.